# Trying to recall title of a story about a fencer who befriended dwarfs and fought villans with the help of a metal ball with tentacles?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I believe the hero happens upon the space worlds as an accidental  byproduct of meeting dwarfs.

Comment: Please, to help you, we're going to need a lot more details.  Anything you can add would be helpful:  when you read it (year), what language, etc.  Your best bet is to look at the answers to [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see any that you can [edit] in.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are referring to is "Time Bandits" by Terry Gilliam.
It has dwarves who are using a map of holes in space/time to rob people from different eras. The map was made by God and he is trying to find them and his map. There is an evil character who fights the dwarves with tentacle like weapons that come out of his body.

Comment: I believe they're asking about a book, specifically.